# Differencing Two String Lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, except

I am trying to create a string list that contains all of the items that are different between List A and List B.  I have the following code, and I feel that I am close, but I am getting syntax errors on the last line.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
 List<string> ListA = new List<string>(textBox_CompareListA.Text.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
 List<string> ListB = new List<string>(textBox_CompareListB.Text.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

 List<string> DifferencesList = ListA.Except(ListB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Union(ListB.Except(ListA, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Here is the error: http://screencast.com/t/Y8S9LC2Y

[image: Syntax Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try calling [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to get the List from your query expression.

```
List<string> DifferencesList = ListA.Except(ListB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Union(ListB.Except(ListA, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't resist pointing out this:

```
 List<string> diffs = ListA.Union(ListB).Except(ListA.Intersect(ListB)).ToList();
```

Depending on your data it could be faster (I believe if the Intersection is small).

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line code from :

```
List<string> DifferencesList = ListA.Except(ListB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Union(ListB.Except(ListA, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

To :

```
var DifferencesList = ListA.Except(ListB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Union(ListB.Except(ListA, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Or :

```
IEnumerable<string> DifferencesList = ListA.Except(ListB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Union(ListB.Except(ListA, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```